# Generate a group with Cyclotomic representation in GAP

Tags: matrices, gap, cyclotomic-fields

I am trying to create a matrix group in GAP, but I am having problems because "it runs out of memory". The group in question is related to **GL(2,3)**.

The problem is that I do not know if I am representing in the correct form the Cyclotomic numbers.

So, GAP manual says that the way to use this number is E(n): $e_n = \text{exp}(2π i/n)$, and my matrix elements have the form 
$$\frac{1}{2}\left[exp\left(\frac{2\,i\pi}{8}\right)-exp\left(\frac{2\,i\pi\,3}{8}\right)\right]$$
I am using the form

```
(1/2)*(E(8)-E(8)^3)
```

Using this form, I try to generate all the 48 elements of the group, as

```
g:=[[(1/2)*(E(8)-E(8)^3),(1/2)*(E(3)-E(8)^3)],
    [(1/2)*(E(8)-E(8)^3),(1/2)*(-E(8)+E(8)^3)]];
h:=[[E(8)^3,0],[0,E(8)]];

G:=Group(g,h);
```

and the elements:

```
Elements(G);
```

the problem is that at the end I obtain the error

```
gap: cannot extend the workspace any more!
```

Evidently, I am doing something wrong but I am not sure what. I am new In GAP and group theory, so I am not sure what is happening. Does anybody has a clue?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The element you write would be `1/2*(E(8)-E(8)^3`, is this a typo? Otherwise you migth want to indicate what seems to fail and what the group is.

Comment: @ahulpke You are right, I had a typo thanks. I already tried to explain better the error in the question space,

Comment: @ahulpke Sorry, there was a typo, but now the matrices are correct. But now that you mention I know the order of the second matrix is 4, but I am not sure the order of the first matrix.

Comment: If you fix the `3` in the first row of `g` to an `8`, then you get finite order and a group of order 48 as expected.

Comment: You also might find the shortcut `ER(n)` for $\sqrt{n}$ as cyclotomic number convenient.

Comment: @ahulpke Thank you, now with the `8` in `g` everything works. Now, with the correct matrix, I could try to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Just to have the question answered:]

The problem will go away once typing mistakes have been fixed.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to clarify. Yes, I changed the element $E(3)$ to $E(8)$ and now the group is finite.